# Dialog to full screen on scroll animation

Tags: android, android-layout

The scenario: There is a **Dialog** whose content is larger than the screen's height therefore scrolling is needed to see everything in the **Dialog**. Because scrolling should be avoided in **Dialogs** (according to [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/components/dialogs#behavior)) I was trying to find the way to omit that issue.

The solution?: I noticed that in Google Play Store there is a dialog that when scrolled down it animates smoothly into a full screen. If I get to the top of the screen again and scroll up, it becomes the **Dialog** again and when scrolled even further it dismisses the dialog. I was wondering whether there is an easy solution that would allow this kind of transition or do I have to add some kind of *OnScroll()* listeners manually?

[image]

Comment: I guess it using [Full-Screen Dialog Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#FullscreenDialog) and some customized motion layout for drag and fullscreen effect